# How to leave inner template(s) of template template (+template) parameters unspecified

Tags: c++, template-templates

How to make the following code compile?

```
#include "vector"

template<
    template<class> class Container
> Container<int> f(int i) {
    return Container<int>{i};
}

int main() {
    return f<std::vector>(1)[0];
}
```

GCC-4.8.2 complains:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'f(int)'
note: template<template<class> class Container> Container<int> f(int)
```

The actual problem is how can I allow the caller to specify which Eigen linear algebra solver (e.g. http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1BiCGSTAB.html) to use inside a function when the only change in code would be to comment out another line from:

```
Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<Scalar_T>> solver;
//Eigen::ConjugateGradient<Eigen::SparseMatrix<Scalar_T>> solver;
//Eigen::SimplicialCholesky<Eigen::SparseMatrix<Scalar_T>> solver;
```

Currently the function starts as:

```
template<
    template<class> class Eigen_Solver_T,
    class Scalar_T
> std::vector<Scalar_T> solve(...)
```

, I don't want the caller to also have to give Eigen::SparseMatrix or, instead, only give

```
Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<Scalar_T>>
```

as template parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to understand what kind of template you have. In this case, `std::vector` has *two* type parameters:

```
template <typename T, template <typename, typename> class C>
C<T> foo()
{
    return C<T>();
}
```

More generally you may like to use a variadic signature, which is permissible even for non-variadic templates:

```
template <typename T, template <typename...> class C>
C<T> bar()
{
    return C<T>();
}
```

Usage:

```
foo<int, std::vector>();    // OK, returns std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>
bar<int, std::vector>();    // OK, ditto
bar<int, std::set>();       // also OK
```

Comment: Thanks, I did try that but turns out I gave the arguments in the wrong order (foo<vector, int>) and GCC's error message was not helpful enough. The last line was "note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:" but nothing more was printed. Clang at least mentions an invalid template parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `std::vector` as the template argument for your function since `std::vector` is defined as:

```
template<
    class T,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<T>
> class vector;
```

However, you can use the template aliasing feature of C++11 to accomplish your goal.

```
#include <vector>

template<
    template<class> class Container
> Container<int> f(int i) {
    return Container<int>{i};
}

template <typename T>
using MyVector = std::vector<T>;

int main() {
    return f<MyVector>(1)[0];
}
```